# whats an appropriate word to describe someone who embarrassed themselves a lot?

Tags: adjectives

Im looking for a word to describe a friend who always seems to embaresses themselves.

Comment: On purpose, to amuse people? Because they lack self-confidence in social contexts? Because they happen to hang out with people who like teasing them?

Comment: "He is rather clumsy.  But, I wouldn't describe him as such." -- You just did.

Comment: @thomj1332 hehehehe I guess I did. What I meant with that is, although he places himself in a 'oh he is clumsy' situation, he has good reflexes. He is just unaware of his surroundings.

Comment: @FumbleFingers no not on purpose, he is rather clumsy. But I wouldn't describe him as such. He embarresses himself by causing a scene, says something wrong in unappropriate time, knocking things down by accident, etc. I don't think himlack self-confidence, embarrassing things just happen to him.

Comment: Does this person *care* about being embarrassed? Or is it just that *you* feel embarrassed (on his behalf)? Perhaps because he's an unconventional / bohemian character (in which case he might be quite used to people around him feeling "awkward", even if *he* doesn't).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I mean, he does get embarrassed when he does something embarrassing (like most people) but we always laugh it out afterwards.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems like a *socially **awkward*** or ***gauche*** person.

ODO:

> **[awkward](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/awkward)**
>
> *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **2** Causing or feeling embarrassment or inconvenience.
>
> ‘After a few such trips, I became bolder, and I got myself into quite
> a few awkward or embarrassing situations as a result.’
>
> **3** Not smooth or graceful; ungainly.
>
> ‘Luther's awkward movements impeded his progress’
>
> **[gauche](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/gauche)**
>
> **ADJECTIVE**
>
> Lacking ease or grace; unsophisticated and socially awkward.
>
> ‘I've been told repeatedly that the residents of LA never ask for
> autographs - it's considered gauche.’